# Group `dt` and `dd` in `span` under `dl`

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to show or hide certain `dt`/`dd` groups within a `dl`. Is this valid HTML? Should browsers complain about this or is it legit? I've looked at the `dl` specs but couldn't find anything saying that the `dl` can contain something other than `dt` and `dd` children. I need to do this as I'm using `angularJS` which provides this neat way of adding or removing elements from the `DOM`

```
<dl>
  <dt>Term</dt>
  <dd>Definition</dd>

  <span ng-if="true">
    <dt>Term 2</dt>
    <dd>Definition 2</dd>
  </span>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid HTML5, because the content model of [`dl`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element) elements is

> Zero or more groups each consisting of one or more `dt` elements
>   followed by one or more `dd` elements, optionally intermixed with
>   [script-supporting elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#script-supporting-elements-0).

So `dl` can't contain `span`, but most browsers will render it correctly.

Instead of `span`, I suggest using [`di`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml2/mod-list.html#edef_list_di) elements. They are invalid HTML5 too, but were valid in XHTML2.

```
<dl>
  <dt>Term</dt>
  <dd>Definition</dd>
  <di ng-if="true">
    <dt>Term 2</dt>
    <dd>Definition 2</dd>
  </di>
</dl>
```

However, the downside is that old IE won't recognize `di`, so it won't apply CSS styles to them unless you use `document.createElement('di')` while the document is loading.

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of `di` but since it appears to be the 'less wrong' way of doing what I'm trying to achieve, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: XHTML 2.0 is an expired draft (formally now published as a WG Note, giving it no authority, it isn’t even in the “standards track”), and `di` has no browser support: it is parsed as unknown element. It is better to use `span` or `div`, which are properly recognized by all browsers—equally invalid formally, but more practical.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Yes I know that. But I don't care if `<di>` elements are `HTMLUnknownElement`s, I prefer them because I think they are necessary and that not including them in HTML5 was an error. But `<span>` or `<div>` elements make no sense inside `<dl>`.

Answer (score 4):

Grouping with `div` in `dl` is now valid per WHATWG HTML, see
https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-dl-element

> ### The dl element
>
> #### Content model:
>
> Either: Zero or more groups each consisting of one or more `dt` elements followed by one or more `dd` elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.
>
> Or: One or more `div` elements, optionally intermixed with script-supporting elements.

```html
<dl>
 <div>
  <dt> Last modified time </dt>
  <dd> 2004-12-23T23:33Z </dd>
 </div>
 <div>
  <dt> Recommended update interval </dt>
  <dd> 60s </dd>
 </div>
 <div>
  <dt> Authors </dt>
  <dt> Editors </dt>
  <dd> Robert Rothman </dd>
  <dd> Daniel Jackson </dd>
 </div>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

That will probably work in most browsers but it is not valid HTML. It could also break some CSS. You probably need to just use 2 `ng-if` directives

```
<dt ng-if="true">Term 2</dt>
<dd ng-if="true">Definition 2</dd>
```

Note that if you need to do something like iterate over a list of items you can use angular's `ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`.

```
<dt ng-repeat-start="item in list">Term 2</dt>
<dd ng-repeat-end>Definition 2</dd>
```

Comment: Thanks. That's true but unfortunately I have loads of elements which I need to group and I don't have them in an array so I was trying to do this in order to avoid writing ng-if multiple times